# should I rework this 3/4" main water line into 1/2" branch circuits?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

The main water line into my house is 3/4". It then sizes down to 1/2" for the distribution throughout the house. I am wondering about the transition from 3/4" to 1/2" - what is the right way for that to look?

Specifically, my 3/4" line transitions down to 1/2" in the straight pipe before it branches off to any of the other lines. This seems to me it would create a choke point that would undermine the benefit of 3/4". Would it be better to extend 3/4" line to meet some other circuits, or is the current setup typical?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would definitely be better for all the 1/2" lines to come individually off the 3/4" line, but it is hard to say if it would be worth it to redo the line. Modern residential water use in most places stressed conservation. Your showers may be so low flow that the 1/2" line supplies enough volume without a bothersome pressure drop.

Comment: The answer to the related question, "will it make a difference?", depends on whether you have a problem. Do you notice troublesome drops in water pressure today? e.g., clothes washer filling or toilet flushed while someone showers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ Roberto, I would change the water line to exactly what you show in your bottom picture. In my home there are no 1/2X1/2X1/2" tees. All the 1/2" lines are teed off the 3/4" line and when one device uses water, say someone flushes a toilet, the person in the shower does not see a reduction of water flow or a major temperature change in the shower water. There have been many posts where people ask "how do I keep adequate water flow when I have 1/2" plumbing", Your drawing is the answer. This works for me.